# Help with Test Coverage for redirect

Tags: apex, unit-test

Here is the code for the class I still need to cover

```
Public class SearchEvent {

    ...bunch of other code ...

    public PageReference redirect(){
            
            String myKey = [SELECT Key__c FROM Setting__mdt WHERE Organization_Id__c = :runningOrg.Id].Key__c;    
            
        String URL='https://myurl.com/' + myKey + '?accId=12345&sourceId=56789&svcType=myType&name=my name';
            PageReference mycheck=new PageReference(URL);
            mycheck.setRedirect(true);
            return mycheck;
        }
}
```

Here is the code coverage I am attempting

```
SearchEvent  instance = new SearchEvent ();
    PageReference mycheck =  instance.redirect();
    String myKey = [SELECT Key__c FROM Setting__mdt WHERE Organization_Id__c = :SearchEvent.runningOrg.Id].Key__c;   
    system.assertEqual(getFeedback.getUrl(),'https://myurl.com/' + myKey + '?accId=12345&sourceId=56789&svcType=myType&name=my name');
```

I am getting an error on the system asssertion: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void assertEqual(String, String) from the type System.

Can someone help tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You should revisit your previous questions and accept the answers that helped you the most (if the question did receive answers). It is optional, but it signals a few things. 1) That your problem has been solved, and you don't require any more help with it. 2) For other people that find their way to your question via google (or other search engine) that the solution worked for you, and it is worth a shot for them. 3) It's part of the stackexchange culture. It's a way of thanking the people who go out of their way to help you, and you both get a bump in reputation score (gotta get those points)

Comment: I understand that. I left a comment seeing that I needed to test it which would take some time. As soon as I have tested it I will go back and mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method name isn't `assertEqual()`, but rather `assertEquals()`. I.e. it's the plural, and you need to add an 's'.

For issues like these, probably the first place that I would point you to is the [System Class Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_system.htm) documentation, which is easily found by searching for "system class apex" (or generally "x class apex") in your search engine of choice.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't catch the typo. It seems to work, however I am now running into other issues having to do with missing data in the org. I will come back and mark this as the answer when I can test.

Comment: Thanks. I had to make some other adjustments but this did the trick. Thanks for your help.